# Woocommerce shop page custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

As I understand by default Woocommerce shop page uses product archive template. What I am looking for, is to use a custom template for shop page.

Here is what I did:

1. Create template "my-shop"
2. Create page "My shop" -> choose template "my-shop"
3. Choose "My shop" as Woocommerce shop page

But none of the changes I made to "my-shop" template are present on the shop page.

What am I missing here? I would not like to change product archive itself, just the shop page.

Is there a way to disable product archive from being a default for shop page?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264723/woocommerce-on-page-templates/37272084#37272084

Answer (score 6):

I know it's too late and you may have figured it out by now. In any case, the changes that you would like to make to the WooCommerce Shop Page need to be done in the `archive-product.php` and it would be safer to create a child theme and do these changes. Making enhancements and customizations in a Child theme is best practice so that you can update the parent theme at any time and it won't affect your store.

I hope this helps, for more information on how you can use WooCommerce short-codes to customize your store can be found [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).

Answer (score 3):

To add to Silver Ringvee's answer - he used `is_page` but that only works on wordpress pages.  For woocommerce you need to use something like `is_woocommerce()` .  See [Woocommerce conditional tags page.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

My example code uses the `is_shop` conditional tag as that was the page you wanted to change. the code `get_template_part( 'content', 'shop' );` will call the file content-shop.php in your theme root folder.  This code is to be added at the top of `wp-content\themes\*theme*\woocommerce\archive-product.php` that you can copy from `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\archive-product.php`

You can add it just before `get_header( 'shop' );` line 23 in my file - and the entire page will be drawn from your template.  If you want to keep the header of the shop page, then put this code after the `get_header` code.  Remember to include a footer in your file as well

```
if (is_shop()) {
 get_template_part( 'content', 'shop' );
} else  {  
#normal archive-product code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution (not perfect) that I figured to work best, until someone finds a way to actually change the template from dashboard:

Adding:

```
<?php
if (is_page( 'Page Title' ) ):
  # Do your stuff
endif;
?>
```

to `content-product.php` in my theme's woocommerce folder.

Answer (score 0):

### TESTED IN WP 6.2 & WooCommerce 8.2.0

#### Hello everyone

If you want to `use the theme`, `use what others have said`, but **if you want to use in** `plugin`, follow my guide.

Like you, I want to be in `shop_loop` , so I use the hooks provided by woocommerce

We will check content-product.php hooks together

`content-product.php` Location: `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\content-product.php` you can check what hook in this file and remove it by `remove_action`

#### READ IT :P ... it's important things!

This is **ALL** hooks in this **date** & in this **version** in `content-product.php` file:

**EXAMPLE: "HOOK" => function Name** : description

**"woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item"** => **woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open** : for open `<a>` tag so user can click it. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open)

**"woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title"** => **woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash** : show sale flash. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash)

**"woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title"** => **woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail** : get product thumbnail. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail)

**"woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title"** => **woocommerce_template_loop_product_title** : show `h2` tag title. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_product_title)

**"woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title"** => **woocommerce_template_loop_rating** : show rating. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_rating)

**"woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title"** => **woocommerce_template_loop_price** : show price. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_price)

**"woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item"** => **woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close** : close `a` tag. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close)

**"woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item"** => **woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart** : show add_to_cart button. [source](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart)

#### AFTER READ this

With the help of source, we can rewrite these hooks with our function
You Can Clear Hook and remove this function like me :

```
// IMPORTANT: pls change function name :P i copy this in my plugin source
add_action('wp_head', 'kdev_remove_all_actions_in_shop', 99);
function kdev_remove_all_actions_in_shop(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important, without it HOOK will be remove in All pages
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        // remove All Action in content-product & rewrite them :P
        // Don't Change This Part [START]
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 
'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash');
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5);
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_price');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5);
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
       // Don't Change this Part HERE [END]
    }
}
```

AND write it ONE BY ONE:

```
function kdev_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        global $product;
        $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'kdev_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item');
...
```

and do other like this...

Here is my **full Source Code** , **PLEASE change function names :P** :

```
// HERE IS MY CODE TO CHANGE SHOP CATEGORY IN PLUGN [START]
function kdev_remove_all_actions_in_shop(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important, without it HOOK will be remove in All pages
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        // remove All Action in content-product & rewrite them :P
        // Don't Change This Part [START]
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash');
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5);
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price');
        //
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5);
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    // Don't Change this Part HERE [END]
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'kdev_remove_all_actions_in_shop', 99);
function kdev_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        global $product;
        $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'kdev_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item');
function kdev_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        global $product;
        // Show Sale
        wc_get_template( 'loop/sale-flash.php' );
        // Show Thumbnail
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'kdev_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title');
function kdev_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        global $product;
        echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'kdev_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title');
function kdev_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        global $product;
        // Show Rating
        wc_get_template( 'loop/rating.php' );
        // Show Price
        wc_get_template( 'loop/price.php' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'kdev_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title');
function kdev_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item(){
    // IMPORTANT: this if is important
    if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()){
        global $product;
        // Close A Tag First
        echo '</a>';
        // Show Add To Cart. 
        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); // source: https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'kdev_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item');
// HERE IS MY CODE TO CHANGE SHOP CATEGORY IN PLUGN [END]
```

#### Sorry if my English is not correct. I have taken help from Google translator. I hope it will help you

Answer (score -2):

If you prefer to go with code, you can create a redirect from the original shop page to your page via wp_redirect.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'bc_010101_redirect_woo_pages');
function bc_010101_redirect_woo_pages()
{


 if (is_shop())
 {

  wp_redirect('your_shop_url_here');
  exit;
 }
}
```

More detailed tutorial can be found [here](https://www.binarycarpenter.com/guide-customize-woocommerce-shop-page-with-page-builder-elementor-beaver/)

Comment: Isn't that a bad idea from a performance perspective, adding 1 redirect to every homepage visit?

Answer (score -15):

This is not possible to create custom template for shop page , just copy and paste woocommerce Templates into you theme folder and Try to work in content-product.php template .

Comment: Woocommerce is open source.  Everything is possible.

Comment: Using child theme ,  we can customize it.